# Mavericks issue: All windows auto hide except the active app one(s)

Tags: osx-mavericks

As soon as I launch or re-open an app all other windows from other running apps auto hide. 
So only windows for the app most recently opened are accessible.

Question: How can I disable this behavior?

I'm running OS X 10.9.2 (Mavericks) on a MacBook Air 2012

P.S. English is not my native language, so I apologize for my English and I hope you understand my question)

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause of this behaviour!

I asked myself what has been changed on my MacBook Air recently and the only thing I could think of was installation of the OS X app Keyboard Maestro.
I gave a look at Keyboard Maestro’s Preferences and noticed that the General section contains an option ’Always Hide Other Applications’ with a toggle/checkbox. I noticed it was  switched on/enabled! 
I toggled that option and the issue is gone.

By the way,  I don’t understand why this option is available in Keyboard Maestro. I can’t think of a situation where I want that option switched on.